# iOS 7 SDK - UI Navigation Bar is sometimes darker and sometimes not. But why?

Tags: ios, navigation

I am working on porting my app to iOS 7 and it works very good except one thing. I use the new Translucent background and did not turn it off.

I just noticed that my navigation bar is a little bit darker as the ABUnknownPersonViewController delegate navigationbar. I attached a screenshot. Can someone explain me  this?

I would like to have the exact same navigation bar color as in the ABUnknownPersonViewController as default.

[image: The navigation bar is darker here...]

[image: The navigation bar is lighter here.. this is what i want everywhere]

I hope someone can explain me this.

Greetings

Answer (score 1):

I just figured it out myself. The navigation bar color changes because i  use the following line of code:

```
        if ([view respondsToSelector:@selector(edgesForExtendedLayout)])
           [view setEdgesForExtendedLayout: UIRectEdgeNone];
```