# Why is my navigation item/bar very dark in colour?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, colors, uiwebview

I am building a help screen view controller of my app. It basically contains a `UIWebView` because I want to use HTML to display the help text. There is also another view controller which is kind of the "main" VC. There is a "Present as Popover" segue connecting the two.

From the IB, I see this:

[image]

I have an unwind segue that unwinds to the main VC. It will be triggered if the user taps the "Done" button.

And here is my code:

```
import UIKit

class HelpViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var webView: UIWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
        let htmlString = "You don't need to know about this."
        webView.loadHTMLString(htmlString, baseURL: nil)
    }

    @IBAction func doneClicked(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        performSegueWithIdentifier("exitToMain", sender: self)
    }
}
```

And the unwind segues are working perfectly but the navigation bar is somehow very dark in colour!

[image]

I don't know what's happening here. I checked out this question

[iOS 7 SDK - UI Navigation Bar is sometimes darker and sometimes not. But why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19497395/ios-7-sdk-ui-navigation-bar-is-sometimes-darker-and-sometimes-not-but-why)

The asker said that's because of a piece of code that he wrote but I swear I didn't use the same code as he did (from my limited obj-c to swift translation knowledge)!

Anyway, here is the relevant storyboard hierarchy thingy:

[image]

What causes this problem and how to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved the problem by setting the background colour of the `UIWebView` to white. And the navigation bar turns white!

I found this by observing how the colour changes when I scroll the web view up and down. I saw that initially it is kinda grey. But when I scrolled down to the white part of the web view, it changes to white. I deduced that the grey colour is actually the web view's background property and the navigation bar is kind of translucent.

And that's why setting the background colour to white fixes this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Stretch the web view through the bottom of the navigation bar and set `automaticallyAdjustScrollviewInsets` to true. That would adjust the scroll view inset to show the content at the right content.

Comment: You mean I should stretch the web view so that some of it is covered by the nav bar?

Comment: Yes, and that's where the automaticallyadjustscrollviewInsets come.

Answer (score 1):

did you try this

```
self.navigationController!.navigationBar.translucent = true
```